# my div element not showing after adding runat attribute but can acess its ID at code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this div element in my .aspx page

```
    <div ID="divFilesGrid" runat = "server" > </div>
```

This div holds an Id for my dynamic grid which is in my .cs page. So If i remove this div element my grid will be removed as well.
aspx:

```
         $('#divFilesGrid').html(AJAX.getExtraData('FilesList'));



           <table style="width: 100%">
           <tr>
            <td class="label" style="width:15%">
            Upload File
            </td>
           td class="description" >
           <input type="file" ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" 
           class="largeTextField"  multiple="multiple" style="width:260px;"/>
             <input type="button" ID="btnUpload" runat="server" 
            value="Upload" onserverclick="Upload" />
            </td>
              </tr>
             </table>
          <div ID="divFilesGrid" runat = "server"> </div>
     </div>
            </div>

           </div>


      </asp:Content>
```

.cs code:

```
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                html += "<tr class=\"GreyBorder\" id='tblFilesGrid_" + 
        dr["Id"].ToString() + "' pkid=\"" + dr["id"].ToString() + "\"  
           class=\"DataRow\">";
                html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" style=\"text-align:center 
            !important;\">" + Count + "</td>";
                html += "<td  align=\"center\" >" + dr["Name"] + "</td> ";



                html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" align='center'><input 
          type=\"button\"  id=\"btnView\" onserverclick=\"ShowDocument\" 
              runat=\"server\"/></td>";
                html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" align='center'><img 
             title='remove' onclick='return DeleteRow(this)'  
                src='../../images/delete.png'></td>";



                html += "</tr>";
                Count++;


            }
        }
```

I want to access my onclick function ShowDocument at code behind but If I add runat attribute to my div element above, my grid disappears but I can access its ID at code behind. Removing attribute makes my grid appear but since I need to access it at code behind, I need to add runat attribute. Why is it happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where are you using divFilesGrid in your code-behind??

Comment: I just need to access my function of my grid ShowDocument at my code behind. I am not really using that div anywhere at code behind. That is why I added runat attribute. My whole grid is in .cs actually

Comment: I edited my question to add my code behind as well. Can you please check what is the problem?

Comment: What are you getting while debugging?

Comment: I have done debugging and it gives me no error or does not crash. Just the grid disappears.

Comment: OK.Wait I'll check. Are you doing Response.Write(html ) in your foreach loop

Comment: No. I have put the code for my grid as well. I am not using Response.Write

Comment: Post your complete aspx and .cs code

Comment: Added both aspx and cs

Comment: Please help! Would be apprecaited

Comment: You are not accessing getFilesGrid() method anywhere in your aspx code. so how it is gonna get called???

Comment: I am acessing it. updated the cs code

Comment: I have created an arraylist in my cs and accessing that grid in aspx through  $('#divFilesGrid').html(AJAX.getExtraData('FilesList'));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207728/discussion-between-unknown-and-atk).

Comment: I got your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your aspx page.

Since you are using content page, its id cannot be accessed directly.

```
$('#<%=divFilesGrid.ClientID%>').html(AJAX.getExtraData('FilesList'));
```

Comment: do you have runat=server on divFilesGrid ??

Comment: Yes I have. Are you sure about this line? $('#<%=divFilesGrid.ClientID%>').html(AJAX.getExtraData('FilesList'));

Comment: OOPS i missed a # in my answer. I have updated it check now

Comment: Done.Thanks again!

Comment: One more thing please

Comment: html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" align='center'><input type=\"button\"  id=\"btnView\" onserverclick=\"ShowDocument\" runat=\"server\"/></td>"; Is this correct from my grid?

Comment: When i click on button, its not trigerring

Comment: I am not sure but i guess since you have runat=server you need to use onclick instead of onserverclick

Comment: I dont think I need to add runat attribute now in this line

Comment: what would be the correct format to write? onclick says function is not defined